# Xpath: detecting existence of the node with specific data

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Here are two excerpts of my xml.

Excerpt I:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Attribute Name</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input>
        <div class="formCellError">Error message</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Excerpt II:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>
            <b>
                <label>Attribute Name</label>
            </b>
        </span>
        <input>
        <div class="formCellError">Error message</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the structure of theese nodes differs. In the 1st excerpt `<label>` and `<div>` are inside the same `<td>` tag, whilst in the 2nd excerpt `<label>` and `<div>` are inside different `<td>` tags.

I need to test, that there is a node with error message in the same `<td>` node, or at least in the preceding sibling `<td>` node. The `<td>` node is specified by the label

Do you have an idea, how to detect existence of nodes with the single X-path expression? I've designed a solution, which is retrieving `<tr>` tag and then analyze it, but it too complicated to support and quite slow.

Comment: *how to detect existence of nodes with the single X-path expression*.. which nodes you want to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath expression detects specific error situated next to specific attribute. Work nice for Excerpt I and Excerpt II

```
//tr[//label/text()='Attribute Name' and //div[@class='formCellError' and text()='Error message'] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples, you're not looking for errors in the first preceding sibling, but *following* sibling. If not, modify the query to use the `preceding-sibling` axis step instead.

You might have to remove the `(: comments :)` before being able to run; I used the XQuery comment syntax for explaining the query.

```
//td                                  (: find table cells :)
  [.//label]                          (: having a label in it :)
  [
    .//div[@class='formCellError']    (: and an error in the same cell :)
      or
    following-sibling::td[1]//div[@class='formCellError'] (: the following cell :)
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking how you can find all the TR nodes that contain a DIV with the class of "formCellError" then you can do that with this XPath:

```
//tr[.//div[@class='formCellError']]
```

If you're asking how to find all Labels that are in a TR that contains a DIV with the class of "formCellError" then use this XPath:

```
//tr[.//div[@class='formCellError']]//label
```